# How to evaluate $f(2^73^55^6)=?$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am stuck on the following problem and do not know how to proceed:

> We define a function  $f(N)=\text{ sum of digits of N,expressed as decimal number}$ e.g.$f(137)=1+3+7=11$. Then I have to evaluate $f(2^73^55^6)=?$

Can someone explain? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: An easy start is simply removing $2^65^6 = 10^6$ since that gives only zeroes at the right end..

Comment: Hint: $2^73^55^6=(2^65^6)2^13^5=(10^6)2^13^5$

Comment: Note also that the answer will be divisible by $9$ because the sum of the digits of a number divisible by $9$ is also divisible by $9$. With the other hint and just estimating there are at most three non-zero digits, and since the number is even this reduces to two possibilities for the digit sum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have that $2^73^55^6=10^6\cdot 2 \cdot 3^5$
Since powers of 10 just add zeroes you have that it's equal to $f(2\cdot 3^5)=f(486)=18$

Answer (score 1):

No idea how formatting works here but here we go.

$2^7  3^5  5^6 = 486000000$

$f(2^7  3^5  5^6) = f(486000000)$

$f(486000000) = 4 + 8 + 6 + 0 + ... + 0 = 18$

It looks like it just simplified the larger number into its prime factors to save space.

edit: learned how to format. neat